# Remove object property which inside an array which inside an object which inside an array without looping on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I have an array which has objects I want to remove all properties which have the key "isCorrect"
from the object without looping on the primary array or changing its value to false.

```
[ { "arrangement": 1, "question": "mijn", "answers": [ { "answer": "nmiou", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "nkj", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nk", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "jln", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 2, "question": "kjn", "answers": [ { "answer": "kjn", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "kj", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nkj", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 3, "question": "jn", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nn", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 4, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 5, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 6, "question": "nn", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 7, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 8, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "nkokj", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nj", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nkj", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 9, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "njk", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "nkjn", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "jk", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nkj", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 10, "question": "i", "answers": [ { "answer": "i", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "ii", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "i", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "i", "isCorrect": false } ] } ]
```

It can be done with looping but it takes time and performance,

```js
let primaryArray = [ { "arrangement": 3, "question": "jn", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nn", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 4, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 5, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 6, "question": "nn", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 7, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 8, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "n", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "nkokj", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nj", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nkj", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 9, "question": "n", "answers": [ { "answer": "njk", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "nkjn", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "jk", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "nkj", "isCorrect": false } ] }, { "arrangement": 10, "question": "i", "answers": [ { "answer": "i", "isCorrect": true }, { "answer": "ii", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "i", "isCorrect": false }, { "answer": "i", "isCorrect": false } ] } ]

primaryArray.map((q)=>{
  q.answers[0].isCorrect = false;
})
console.log(primaryArray)
```

Comment: Then you've to refer all those properties manually one by one. Why such a limitation preventing the use of rational methods?

Comment: "_it takes time and performance_" No, it really doesn't, unless the array has the length of more than a couple of tens of millions.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the isCorrect property from the objects in the array, you can use the map method to iterate over the array and the delete operator to remove the property from each object.

Something like this:

```
const updatedArray = array.map(item => {
  delete item.answers.isCorrect;
  return item;
});
```

This should remove "isCorrect" from the "answers" without making changes to the original array i think...

Comment: "_without loop on the main array_" was required.

Comment: Then he has to do it manually lol. I didnt see the "without loop"